# LibGDX rectangle's y-position updates even after collision

Tags: libgdx, collision, overlap, rectangles

I'm working with 2D platformer and I want to make box'es that fall from the sky. And when collision between box and ground occur box'es should stop to fall. Here's my code fo collision detection and update in `Box` class

```
public Box(int x, int y){

        hitBox = new Rectangle(x, y, 64, 64);
        bottom = new Rectangle(x + 5, y, 54, 14);
        top = new Rectangle(x + 5, y + 5 + 50, 54, 14);
        // other code
}
@Override
public void update(float delta) {
    if(!hits){
        velocity -= (1 * delta);
        System.out.println("velc " + velocity);
        hitBox.y += velocity;
        top.y += velocity;
        bottom.y += velocity;
        sprite.setPosition(hitBox.x, hitBox.y);
    }
}

@Override
public int hits2(Rectangle r) {
    if(bottom.overlaps(r)){
        velocity = 0;
        hits = true;
        System.out.println("hit");
        return 1;
    }
    System.out.println("n");
    hits = false;
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my code from `Main` class

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            Box tmpBox = (Box) (list.get(i) instanceof Box ? list.get(i) : null);
            for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++){
                if(tmpBox != null){
                    Brick brick = (Brick) (list.get(j) instanceof Brick ? list.get(j) : null);
                    Box tmpOtherBox = (Box) (list.get(j) instanceof Box ? list.get(j) : null);
                    if(brick != null){ // if collision with ground rectangle
                        tmpBox.hits2(brick.getTop());
                    }
                    if(tmpOtherBox != null && tmpOtherBox.hashCode() != tmpBox.hashCode()){ if collision with other box rectangle
                        tmpBox.hits2(tmpOtherBox.getHitBox());
                    }
                }
            }
            if(tmpBox != null){
                tmpBox.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            }
}
```

But the problem is that when box collides with ground my box still fall down except it velocity is very small. Why I get this strange result? I know that I could just remove `hits = false;` in my `hits2` method and then my box won't fall down when they collides with ground, but still why collision between rectangles work so strange?
**UPDATE:**
 here how it looks [visually](https://vid.me/BijR)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the collision rectangle of the ground by drawing it? and also draw collision of the box and check the collision point. Because I had done that in one of my game, and I was drawing ground rectangle for collision at much bottom so when the actor was going out of screen just think this way it collides.

Collision in libgdx works perfectly with overlap method.

Comment: Thanks, I checked all. Also I update'd my post and add short video about my problem